# What is the difference between value and constant literal in first order logic syntax?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In FOL, there are two **values** true and false;

In FOL, there are two **constant literals** : T and F;

Is there any difference between the both (values and constant literals)?

Can I say that true value is same as constant literal T and  false value as F?

Comment: See also the post [Verum, Falsum, Atoms](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32938/verum-falsum-atoms).

Comment: Can you give a link to a development of FOL that includes two such constant literals? Note that's FOL, not propositional logic! Also note that an exposition where we see those two symbols doesn't suuffice; they have to be explicitly included as "constant literals" _in the language_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1800000/1795140/p213-gordon.pdf?ip=14.139.236.211&id=1795140&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=045416EF4DDA69D9%2EF1486EDFD37746FC%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&__acm__=1549212946_11f5a7b87ae26cc93a15f216570050d5  Page no 2 sec 3.1

Comment: Thanks, but that just gives "An error occurred while processing your request."

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich See the paper titled "First-Order Mixed Integer Linear Programming" by Gordon et al in google scholar

Answer (score 3):

The *constant* literals $\text T$ and $\text F$ are *symbols* of the language (also used : $\top$ and [$\bot$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic))).

The *truth-values* TRUE and FALSE are "objects" : they are e.g. the only two objects used in  the domain of interpretation (the "boolean world" of the classical propositional calculus.

Obviously, the *constant* literals are constant; i.e. interpretations will always assign to the syntactical objects $\text T, \text F$ the truth-values TRUE and FALSE respectively.

---

Usually, the two symbols above are intrduced in *propositional calculus*.

$\bot$ can be used to define negation as : $A \to \bot$ and obviously $\top$ can be defined as $\bot \to \bot$.

But we can develop FOL also with *propositional symbols*, i.e. $0$-ary predicate symbols, and the propositional constant $\bot$.

See e.g. Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA56), page 57.

In this case (see page 66), an interpretation of the sentences $\varphi$ of the language in a structure $\mathfrak A$ is a mapping to $\{ 0, 1 \}$, satisfying (*inter alia*) the condition $[⊥]^{\mathfrak A} = 0$.

Comment: I believe this is simply wrong. In FOL the interpretation of a constant is an element of the "domain". See my answer...

Comment: (In that link you provided they're  said to be atomic formmulae, or 0-ary connectives. II think it's clear that they're talking about propositional logic there; in any case an atomic formula in FOL,, if there is such a thing, is certainly not a "constant literal"..)

Comment: I see you mentioned propositional logic and didn't mention FOL. My claim that this is simply wrong is referring to the idea that T and F are _"constant literals"_ in FOL.

Comment: "But we can develop FOL also with propositional symbols, i.e. 00-ary predicate symbolsy. See van Dalen, Logic and Structure, page 57." And sure enough, the propositional symbols there are __not__ "constant symbols". Two separate categories.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no such "constant literals" in FOL. There may be such symbols used when we talk about FOL, but they are certainly not part of the language of FOL. (The interpretation of a constant literal in a model of a theory in FOL is an element of the "universe" of the model; that makes no sense for $T$ and $F$.)

In case that's not clear, an example. Consider $\mathcal T$, the first-order theory of groups. We can do that without a constant symbol for the identity, or if we wish we can include a constant literal $e$, so we could have an axiom $$\forall x(ex=xe=x)$$in place of the constant-free $$\exists y\forall x(yx=xy=x).$$

Suppose we do include a constant symbol $e$. Now a model of  $\mathcal T$ is exactly a group, and if $G$ is a group the interpretation of $e$ is just the identity element of $G$. If there *is* a constant literal $T$, what element of $G$ would be the interpretation of $T$?

Or consider the first-order theory of ordered fields, with, among other things, constant symbols $0$ and $1$ and a binary predicate $\ge$. If  $c$ is a constant literal the sentence $\forall x(xx\ge c)$ makes sense; in fact it's a theorem if $c$ is $0$ and an anti-theorem if $c$ is $1$. What does that sentence "mean" is $c$ is $T$?

(One could have constant literals T and F in *propositional* logic...)